# Be + adj. or Be + like + adj

Tags: meaning

I saw this line on a TV show:

"He was **like** rich, successful, handsome.I hated that guy."

What's the difference between this one and

"He was rich, successful, handsome.I hated that guy."

Is there any grammatical explanation for this? Or it's just another colloquial English?

Full context:

"Oh, yeah, Robin was spending New Year's with her boyfriend, Derek."

"Derek."

"He was like rich, successful, handsome."

"I hated that guy."

I heard this line from the TV show "How I Met Your Mother" Season 1,Episode 11

Answer (score 2):

In these cases, 'like' is being used as a **[filler word](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/fillerterm.htm)**.

Basically it means nothing and is just there to fill a gap while the user is thinking about what they're going to say next in the sentence.